# Why aren't my nested array elements being added together properly?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

[Why I am getting this kinda error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtUNg.png). But when I am calculating products of them, they seem fine.

```js
//The funtion will add all the values in that array....
function addArrayValues(arr) {
  var addition = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      addition += arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  return addition;
}

var addition = addArrayValues([[[23], [34], [54]], [[34], [75]], [[75]], [65]]);
console.log(addition);
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an array of arrays - rather, you have an array of arrays **of arrays**. You need to go 3 levels deep, not just 2:

```js
//The funtion will add all the values in that array....
function addArrayValues(arr){
    var addition=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
            for (var k = 0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++) {
                addition+=arr[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return addition;
}

var addition=addArrayValues([[[23],[34],[54]],[[34],[75]],[[75]],[65]]);
console.log(addition);
```

Or use `.flat` instead:

```js
//The funtion will add all the values in that array....
const addArrayValues = arr => arr
    .flat(2)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

var addition=addArrayValues([[[23],[34],[54]],[[34],[75]],[[75]],[65]]);
console.log(addition);
```

Your original code is implicitly coercing the 3-deep arrays to strings first, so, eg, iterating over

```
[[23],[34],[54]]
```

starts by calculating

```
[23] + [34] + [54]
```

so the arrays are turned to strings during the creation of the `addition` variable.